# How to create a TABLE with both type and inheritor type in Oracle PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, inheritance, plsql, relational-database

I am working on creating a object-relational database in Oracle 11g. I am trying to create a Table that is able to store this two types:

`CREATE TYPE Father (...)`

`CREATE TYPE Son UNDER Father (...)`

I later need to access all Fathers, and also to access Sons and treat them as such. I haven't been able to find the way to create this table.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88542/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CarType AS OBJECT (
 brand          VARCHAR2(30),
 model          VARCHAR2(20),
 MEMBER FUNCTION isSportsCar RETURN NUMBER)
 NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY CarType AS
 MEMBER FUNCTION isSportsCar RETURN NUMBER IS
 BEGIN
   RETURN 0;
 END;
END;
/

CREATE TYPE SportsCarType UNDER CarType (
   TopSpeed NUMBER,
   OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION isSportsCar RETURN NUMBER)
   NOT FINAL;
/

CREATE TYPE BODY SportsCarType AS
 OVERRIDING MEMBER FUNCTION isSportsCar RETURN NUMBER IS
 BEGIN
   RETURN 1;
 END;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE Cars OF CarType (
  CONSTRAINT Cars_PK PRIMARY KEY ( Brand, Model )
)
/


INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ( CarType( 'ACME', 'Jalopy' ) )
/
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ( CarType( 'Ford', 'Model-T' ) )
/
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ( SportsCarType( 'Ferarri', 'Enzo', 221 ) )
/
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES ( SportsCarType( 'Bugatti', 'Vayron', 253.81 ) )
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT brand,
       model,
       c.isSportsCar(),
       TREAT(VALUE(c) AS SportsCarType).TopSpeed
FROM   Cars c
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88542/3/0)**:

```
|   BRAND |   MODEL | C.ISSPORTSCAR() | TREAT(VALUE(C)ASSPORTSCARTYPE).TOPSPEED |
|---------|---------|-----------------|-----------------------------------------|
|    ACME |  Jalopy |               0 |                                  (null) |
|    Ford | Model-T |               0 |                                  (null) |
| Ferarri |    Enzo |               1 |                                     221 |
| Bugatti |  Vayron |               1 |                                  253.81 |
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for two types - just use a single object type for a `Person` and include a `REF` field to another `Person` object to denote the father-son relationship:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01a3e/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TYPE Person AS OBJECT (
  Name VARCHAR2(30),
  Parent REF Person
);

CREATE TABLE People OF Person (
  Name   CONSTRAINT People_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  Parent SCOPE IS People
);

INSERT INTO People VALUES ( 'Adam', NULL );
INSERT INTO People SELECT 'Bob', REF(p) FROM People p WHERE Name = 'Adam';
INSERT INTO People SELECT 'Charles', REF(p) FROM People p WHERE Name = 'Adam';
INSERT INTO People SELECT 'Dave', REF(p) FROM People p WHERE Name = 'Bob';
INSERT INTO People SELECT 'Ed', REF(p) FROM People p WHERE Name = 'Charles';
```

**Query 1**:

Get Bob's father:

```
SELECT Name, p.Parent.Name AS Father FROM People p WHERE Name = 'Bob'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01a3e/4/0)**:

```
| NAME | FATHER |
|------|--------|
|  Bob |   Adam |
```

**Query 2**:

Get Bob's son:

```
SELECT p.Parent.Name AS Name, Name AS Son FROM People p WHERE p.Parent.Name = 'Bob'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/01a3e/4/1)**:

```
| NAME |  SON |
|------|------|
|  Bob | Dave |
```

Comment: This is a way to see it - but I am afraid the names I used where misleading. I am not trying to implement a father-and-son database, those where just the names I used. I actually needed to create a table that could store both the subtype and the supertype of an inheritance relationship.
Other than that it's a very good implementation.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace type complex2 as
  object(rl number, im number,
  not final member procedure  print,
  static function add1(x complex2, y complex2) return complex2,
  order member function val(x complex2) return number) not final

create or replace type complex4 under complex2 
(
       overriding member procedure print
)
/
```